# How to read data from an array using Parse's PFQuery in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I am working on an simple To-Do list iOS app using Parse to save the data. So far, I was able to implement the storing of new data along with retrieving single value of data.

Although the problem I have is, when I try to retrieve all the values using `PFQuery`. This returns an array of `PFObjects` but I am unable to read these individual values, as a null is being returned.

This is how I am going about doing it. Please let me know what I am doing wrong. Thanks.

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"ItemsList"];
[query selectKeys:@[@"itemname"]];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *ItemsArray, NSError *error) {
    // iterate through the objects array, which contains PFObjects for each Student
    ToDoItem *item1= [[ToDoItem alloc]init];

    NSLog(@"Single element:");
    for (PFObject *object in ItemsArray) {
        NSString *name =[object objectForKey:@"itemname"];
        NSLog(@"%@", name);
        item1.itemname = name;
        [self.todoItems addObject:item1];
    } 
}];
```

Comment: You will need to use the `includeKey` option on your `PFQuery` to retrieve the actual objects, otherwise all you get is the object reference.  Also you have the classic mistake of allocating the item outside your loop but adding it inside the loop - so you will end up with multiple references to the one object in your array.  You need to allocate `item1` inside the loop

Comment: @Paulw11 you don't _have_ to use `includeKey`; `selectKeys:` is suffice, since the OP is specifying which column by `name = [object objectForKey:@"itemname"]` my guess is there isn't something in the column to begin with, or you might be right in that the OP is trying to say `item1` is nil, but I might have gotten confused by seeing the NSLog statement for `name`

Comment: No, `selectKeys` will limit the query to only return the value of the `itemname` key, but the value for that key is an array of 'shallow' PFObjects - it only returns the objectID.  You need to issue a fetch against that object to actually get its content.  Using `includeKeys` tells the original query to actually follow the reference and retrieve the referenced object as well

Comment: @Paulw11  `selectKeys` does restrict fields to only included provided keys. you are right, noted.

Comment: I finally go it to work. Turns out I was using the wrong column name i.e 'itemname' instead of 'itemName' and so it was returning a nil value as that column didn't exist in my parse database. @soulshined thanks for pointing out my mistake about the initialization outside the loop. Also it turns out you dont need a 'includeKey' and I was able to retrieve my value with just 'selectKeys/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st things first, please review how to properly format your code in terms of naming structure, this will help you in the future [see here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000146-SW1). Specifically in reference to you naming your array the way you would name a class.

Secondly, 'name' is returning nil because you either don't have a column in your parse backend titled 'itemname', or you don't have any objects in that column, provided you do have one titled 'itemname'

Comment: That is exactly right. Turns out I was using the wrong column name i.e `itemname` instead of `itemName` and so it was returning a nil value as that column didn't exist in my parse database.